# savedInstanceState always null

Tags: java, android

so i have this code in my OnsavedInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String [] a={"haha"};
    savedInstanceState.putStringArray("MyStringarray", a);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Saved array", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and i have this code in my onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "is there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

how come the toast always says not there? i opened the app then switched to another app and it showed the toast saved array but when i reopen the app it says not there even though the bundle should have the string array containing "haha".

Many thanks!

Comment: i think you should call super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); at the end of method

Comment: The method onSaveInstanceState will be called only when the activity is killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `onSaveInstanceState()` you're modifying `savedInstanceState` and not saving this modified object. If `super` does a copy of your `Bundle`, then it will not save this modification.

Try calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` at the end of the method instead.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String [] a={"haha"};
    savedInstanceState.putStringArray("MyStringarray", a);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Saved array", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: if by saving you mean
 savedInstanceState=savedInstanceState.putStringArray("MyStringarray", a);
 that doesn't work if that's not what you mean could you elaborate please?

Comment: No, I mean `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` This does the saving. I put the code for what I mean.

Comment: Check nathan's answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in how you have your activities defined in your manifest. For instance if your activity has the setting android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" I don't think you will receive the saved bundle. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for details on the various activity settings.

You might also check the other overridden methods. For example in you override one and do something odd you could mess the activity stack up. Do you call finish() anywhere in you code, if so remove it and see what happens.

Comment: yeah i double checked my manifest nothing there about that...i also added android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" to the manifest but it's still not working......the problem is it SHOULD work =/ but it isn't and i am not sure why...i did exactly what m0skit0 told me and modified the state and still won't work

Comment: Well in weird cases like this often the best thing to do is just create a clean test project. Just add 1 activity and implement oncreate and onSavedInstance. Once you have it working in a controled environment, see what is different between your test project and the real one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as **onPause()**, which is always called when an activity is being placed in the **background** or on its way to **destruction**, or **onStop()** which is called before **destruction**. One example of when **onPause() and onStop() is called** and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is **no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it. An example when **onPause() is called** and **not onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** is when activity B is launched in front of activity A: the system may **avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of A will stay intact.