# java.lang.NullPointerException on a couple of buttons on the menu bar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i have the following code

```
    imgAbout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAbout);
    imgAbout.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListner(RecipesList.this));

    imgFeedback = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFeedback);
    imgFeedback.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListner(RecipesList.this));

    imgSearchNav = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSearchNav);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
```

where line 4 is giging me the nullpointerexception error is what I could find.

This is from the XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lytTitleBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleApp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/title_app"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/about"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFeedback"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtTitleApp"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/feedback" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is not happening for everyone. I have only 9 crash reports in my developer console out of 500+ active installs

Comment: which is line 4? and there is no button in xml

Comment: imgFeedback.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListner(RecipesList.this));

Comment: Should I be adding a button on the xml ?

Comment: im not really 100% sure whats going on here, it should work if the other one above it is working

Comment: the problem is that the app crashes when I open up the paticular page and I get the following  SavedInstanceState = null

Comment: well you said its only some devices, is it an older device or a newer device?

Comment: This is happening on a nexus 7.

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605017/savedinstancestate-always-null

Comment: Hey unfortunately I tried it and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Figured it out.
This problem was only occuring for high res tablets.
The problem lay with the fact that there was no xml refrence for these buttons in the layout/large folder.